# Firebase Realtime Database - ChildEventListener - Basics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a simple application that adds users to a database.

I'm now trying to display those users on my activity (live update).

I have created a `ListView` and I believe I need to assign the data to that list view (array?) using `addChildEventListener`. I have never done this before so I would appreciate some help getting it working.

Please see my code below. Thank you.

**Users.kt**

```
data class Users(
    var name: String? = "",
    var telephone: String? = ""
)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_user_name"
        android:hint="Name"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_user_telephone"
        android:hint="Telephone"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt_add_user"
        android:text="Add User"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_show_users"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.only_db.ui

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.only_db.R
import com.example.only_db.db.Users
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        bt_add_user.setOnClickListener {

            val name = et_user_name.text.toString().trim()
            val telephone = et_user_telephone.text.toString().trim()

            writeNewUser(name, telephone)
        }

        val childEventListener = object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }

        mDatabase!!.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)

    }

    private fun writeNewUser(name: String, telephone: String) {
        val user = Users(name, telephone)
        mDatabase.child("Users").push().setValue(user)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to display the users, you need to listen to the correct reference. So you are pushing the `User` objects into the `Users` node but you are listening to the `mDatabase` which is actually the root reference. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
mDatabase!!.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)
```

to:

```
mDatabase.child("Users")!!.addChildEventListener(childEventListener)
```

Besides that, add the following line in your `onChildAdded()` method to actually see the result in the logcat.

```
Log.d("TAG", p0.child("name").getValue(String::class.java) + "/" + p0.child("telephone").getValue(String::class.java))
```

And you'll get:

```
John/123456
Lisa/12345688
```

If it works, map the result into a `List<User>` objects and pass it to the adapter.

Comment: Thank you. Let me give that a try :)

Comment: You're welcome. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should be `Log.d("TAG", p0.child("name").getValue(String::class.java) + "/" + p0.child("telephone").getValue(String::class.java))` Does it work now?

Comment: You should check the logcat to see the results by filter after "TAG". Is there something printed out?

Comment: Hi, I just checked the Logcat and it's working. I'm seeing the users in the above format.

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work. If you have hard time implementing the adapter, please post another question, show us where you are stuck, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Ok great. I'll make another post regarding the adapter :)

Comment: Leave here a message with your new question.